# Dynamically loaded user controls disappear after button press c# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to dynamically load instances of user controls on to my main form and it works for the most part when the program is loaded but doesn't work after the corresponding button to load that user control is pressed twice.

I am using the following code to create instance of user controls

```
public partial class patientInfo : UserControl
{
    public static patientInfo _instance;
    public static patientInfo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new patientInfo();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

and this code for loading the instance on MainForm

```
 private void pInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Patient Info
        foreach (Control ctrl in panel3.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Dispose();
        }
        if (!panel3.Controls.Contains(patientInfo.Instance))
        {
            panel3.Controls.Add(patientInfo.Instance);
            patientInfo.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            patientInfo.Instance.BringToFront();

        }
        else
        {
            patientInfo.Instance.BringToFront();

        }
    }
```

If I press this button once the user control will load the way it's supposed to but I press it again the user control will disappear. I am using Dispose because I want to load and unload multiple user controls at different mouse buttons.
Please advise thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the object's `dispose` method releases unmanaged resources, but does not remove the control from the form. In addition to disposing the resource when you're done using it, you need to use the control's `remove` method to remove it from the form. See S.O. answer: [How to programmatically remove Form controls](http://How%20to%20programmatically%20remove%20Form%20controls)

Also, see Microsoft example: [Control.ControlCollection.Remove Method (Control)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx). Code from the example:

```
// Remove the RadioButton control if it exists.
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(panel1.Controls.Contains(removeButton))
   {
      panel1.Controls.Remove(removeButton);
   }
}
```